# How to delete a graph when using FigureCanvasTkAgg

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, graph, tkinter-canvas

I used FigureCanvasTkAgg to make a graphic on the interface, but I don't know how to make the graph disappear from the screen.

```
def actualizarGrafico1():
    global comp
    comp = 1
    e1a1= int(e1.get())*12
    e2a1= int(e2.get())*285
    e3a1= int(e3.get())*8
    e4a1= int(e4.get())*20
    e5a1= int(e5.get())*12
    e6a1= int(e6.get())*15
    nombres = ["Lavarse las manos", "Usar lavadora", "Tirar cadena", "Ducharse", "Regar", "Lavar la loza"]
    tamaño = [e1a1, e2a1, e3a1, e4a1, e5a1, e6a1]
    coloresg =['lightcyan', 'powderblue','paleturquoise', 'lightsteelblue', 'lightskyblue', 'azure']
    explotar = [0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4]

    fig1, ax1= plt.subplots(dpi=50, facecolor ='white', figsize= (9,7))

    plt.title("Gráfico de consumo por actividad", size=25, family="Arial")

    ax1.pie(tamaño, explode=explotar, labels=nombres, colors=coloresg, autopct= "%0.1f%%", shadow=True, startangle=90, radius=0.9)
    
    ax1.axis('equal')
    
    global canvas1
    canvas1=FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=frame)
    canvas1.draw()
    canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
```

I tried to use pack_forget() to make it stop showing and it didn't work. I also used delete to eliminate it, but when pressing the button associated with the function, the copy of the graph appears.

```
def cerrarGrafico1():
    bm.grid_remove()
    canvas1.get_tk_widget().delete("all")
    
    datacmenu.entryconfig("Ingresar",command=actualizarGrafico1())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to clear a FigureCanvasTkAgg canvas in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61615548/how-to-clear-a-figurecanvastkagg-canvas-in-tkinter)